# Custom php function HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php

Ok I wrote a custom PHP function to pull a value from a mysql DB, originally this function was in a class and I was trying to call it form the class, it kept giving me trouble so I moved it locally to the file to troubleshoot it as I wasn't getting any error other than 500, I'm not seeing any errors in /var/log/httpd/error_log and if I comment out the $host variable where I call the getSetting function the script just says failed to login which is expected as I don't supply any info the to ssh login method.

```
<?php
//testing for php
//created by dylan kraklan do not use without permission
//setenforce 0 on host machine is required
//header('Content-type: text/plain');
error_reporting('E_ALL | E_STRICT');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('general.php');
include('config.php');

$database =Database::getInstance();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$gen = new Gen ();

function getSetting($setting) {
 $set_sql = "SELECT value FROM settings WHERE setting='$setting'";
 $set_query =$db->query($set_sql);
 $value_a = $set_query->fetch_assoc();
 $value =$value_a['value'];

 return $value;

 }


$host = getSetting('remote_host');
//$user = $gen->getSetting('remote_user');
//$pass = $gen->getSetting('remote_pass');

//echo $host.$user.$pass;

$ssh = new Net_SSH2($host);

if(!$ssh->login($user, $pass)) {
  exit('Login Failed');
}


print_r($ssh->exec('pwd'));
print_r($ssh->exec('ls -la'));


?>
```

I have enabled all the error logging optiosn I saw in php.ini and I even specified to log errors to php_error.log , I assumed this file would be in the same dir as php.ini (/etc) didn't see it generate. Then I tried switching it to /var/log/httpd/php_error.log and I still don't see it generate.

EDIT: Ok so I found some code that will show me the error, [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Now the error is

> E_NOTICE Error in file �test.php� at line 21: Undefined variable: db Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/html/sync/lib/test.php on line 21 E_ERROR Error in file �test.php� at line 21: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Line 21 is

```
$set_query =$db->query($set_sql);
```

I'm not sure whats wrong with my mysql statement but it seems to be causing issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 0):

After finally getting the error to show up it was caused by the $db variable for the mysqli instance not being available in the function, had to create a new instance within the function.